# django-simple-history save history only when a certain condition is met

Tags: django, django-simple-history

I'm building a project using Django. I want to use the `django-simple-history` package to save the history of a model for every create/update/delete.

I want to save the history only when the superuser or a specific type of user (e.g. supervisor) makes a create/update/delete action, but I don't know how can I implement this condition.

I've tried [this](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/querying_history.html#save-without-a-historical-record) to see if the current user is one of its arguments to use it, but this method seems that it doesn't work properly. Below a portion of my code:

```py
class WFEmployee(models.Model):
    code = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    name_en = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    ...
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    def save_without_historical_record(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(kwargs, 'from save without ')
        try:
            ret = self.save(*args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            pass
        return ret
```

I get nothing in the console when I use `.save_without_historical_record()` it saves the instance but doesn't print anything.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe override the save method?

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if user== supervisor: ##Your condition here
            self.skip_history_when_saving = True
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Is this what you looking for?